# Pages expire very quickly in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a Wicket application and my pages expire very quickly. Why is this, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume that by "My page is Expiring" you mean that the session is expiring?  If so, you can increase the session-timeout in the web.xml of your project:

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The timeout is specified in minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this programatically, by getting the HttpSession of the request and setting MaxInactiveInterval.

```
Integer timeoutInMinutes = 20;
Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
if( request instanceof WebRequest )
{
    WebRequest wr = (WebRequest)request;
    HttpSession session = wr.getHttpServletRequest().getSession();
    if( session != null ) {
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(timeoutInMinutes*60);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `web.xml`, increase the session timeout from 30 minutes to 200 minutes, as shown below:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

should become

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>200</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```